# install plugin built from source code into eclipse?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded CDT plugin source code and have built the whole project by maven. I followed all the maven steps, like maven clean, maven compile ... maven install. Everything worked well. My question is how to install the CDT plug-in which built by myself into eclipse so that I can create a new C/C++ project?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your features and plugin folders to your eclipse where you want to use CDT plugin.